# Server Monitoring - Open Source Alternative to Pulseway

Tags: server, open-source, monitor

As title say i'm looking for something like Pulseway.

Basically i need to monitor 3.000 devices. And i was wondering if there is something where i can install an agent on this devices and monitor/command them securely via a web panel.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use Monitis Server/Device monitoring. They have agent for both Linux and Windows systems. We are using it for checking our internal servers performance. BTW you can install agent in one machine and monitor other devices with your internal network using internal uptime monitoring. On one agent you can setup as many monitor as you need. here is more details http://www.monitis.com/server-monitoring